# How do I prevent rails 3.2 from precompiling individual images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I'm using compass for sprite compilation and I'm wondering how I prevent unused images from getting compiled during `rake assets:precompile`.

For example in a sass file I have.

```
@import "my-icons/*.png";
@include all-my-icons-sprites;
```

After asset precompilation i'm getting the compiled sprite map and all the compiled images:

```
public/assets/my-icons-{hash}.png
public/assets/my-icons/2-{hash}.png
public/assets/my-icons/3-{hash}.png
public/assets/my-icons/4-{hash}.png
public/assets/my-icons/5-{hash}.png
```

My question is how do I stop pre-compilation from compiling individual images in `my-icons/` and only compiling a single sprite map so that I only end up with `public/assets/my-icons-{hash}.png`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. Those images (which are just copies, with a new filename) are not used in your pages so they are not served, they don't consume bandwidth nor memory nor parallel requests.

Comment: They consume disk space and bandwidth at deploy time, this is about to become a serious issue for us. Also, "They don't matter, ignore them" is not a reassuring attitude for something the scale of rails.